# Ejecución aplicacion java desde consola devuelve excepcion pero no desde NetBeans

Tags: java, javafx, consola

Estoy tratando de hacer un ejecutable .exe con una aplicación Java. Antes de ello estoy ejecutando la aplicación desde consola de windows. El problema es que al ejecutuar desde consola me devuelve una excepción pero desde  NetBeans no me aparece ningún problema por lo que no puedo depurar el código. Pego abajo la excepcion que me devuelve la consola:
No sé si el warning que me indica podría ser el causante de la excepción, pero ese mismo warning me lo devuelve NetBeans y se ejecuta la ventana sin problemas.

```
    C:\Users\rafad>java -jar C:\Users\rafad\OneDrive\Documentos\NetBeansProjects\GuardaContrasenas\dist\GuardaContrasenas.jar
ene 25, 2022 2:20:06 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 15.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.311
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$1(LauncherImpl.java:182)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException:
file:/C:/Users/rafad/OneDrive/Documentos/NetBeansProjects/GuardaContrasenas/dist/GuardaContrasenas.jar!/guardacontrasenas/Vistas.fxml

        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
        at guardacontrasenas.GuardaContrasenas.start(GuardaContrasenas.java:18)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:863)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$4(WinApplication.java:185)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Arrays.asList(Unknown Source)
        at guardacontrasenas.VistasController.initialize(VistasController.java:75)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
        ... 17 more
Exception running application guardacontrasenas.GuardaContrasenas
```

[image: Esas son las líneas donde la excepcion señala el nullpointer exception. Esa lista debería leer 4 ficheros que hay en el directorio pero, no lo hace por algún motivo]

Comment: El warning no es importante. La excepción al cargar ese archivo es el lío (tienes un nullPointerException). Qué código genera ese error?

Comment: He editado para añadir una imagen con la linea 75 donde salta el NulPointerException. Cuando lanzo la aplicación con netbeans el ObservableList me muestra 4 ficheros que tengo en el directorio

Comment: Significa que la instancia de la JVM para Netbeans tiene unos permisos y la aplicación tiene otros. De paso, siempre es sano atrapar las excepciones y mostrar un mensaje o algo, digo yo ;)

Comment: Tienes un warning porque estas usando versiones distintas de FXML. Revisa porque cada vez que creas un FXML se axena la version de la misma y luego te puede dar problemas de compatibilidad ya que la estructura o la manera en como el FXML es creado cambia. JAVAFX8 xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" ->  JAVAFX17 xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17"

Comment: Gracias Andy, con lo que me has dicho he conseguido quitar el warning, pero eso no es el problema a la hora de ejecutar desde la consola porque sigue ocurriendo el mismo problema. Hay algo en el entorno de NetBeans que permite la ejecución pero no está en la ejecución desde la consola.

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta en la ruta del archivo FXML que quieres desplegar.

> Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException:
> file:/C:/Users/rafad/OneDrive/Documentos/NetBeansProjects/GuardaContrasenas/dist/GuardaContrasenas.jar!/guardacontrasenas/Vistas.fxml

Esto te esta sucediendo porque la ruta que esta buscando esta dentro del proyecto y la JVM esta tratando de ingresar al JAR. Entonces debes saber como buscar los archivos dentro del proyecto. Generalmente se usa flujo de datos.

Por ejemplo para una imagen lo comun es algo asi fuera del proyecto:

```
new Image(getClass().getResource("recursos/carpeta.png").toExternalForm())
```

para cargar un recurso que esta dentro del projecto

Como  flujo de datos

```
new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("recursos/carpeta.png"));
```

como recurso

```
public Resource recurso(String carpetas){
        Resource resource = 
                    new ClassPathResource(carpetas);
        return resource;
    }
```

Si tienes el FXML en la raiz del proyecto solo colocas el nombre del mismo

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("vistas/Presentacion.fxml"));
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
         scene.setFill(null);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
```

Javafx Normal

```
 public Parent cargarFXML(String rutaFXML) {
        // /stdxml/vista/auxiliares/Modelo1.fxml
        Parent root = null;
       // FXMLLoader loader = null;
        
                
        try {
            
          // loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(rutaFXML)).load();
           root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(rutaFXML));
          // root = loader.load();
           
           
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(VentanaServiceImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        
        return root;
    }
```

Pero si esta en otra ruta debes colocarla completa (SPRING BOOT + JAVAFX)

```
public Parent cargadorFXML(String nombreVentana) {
        Parent root = null;
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader;

        fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(springContext::getBean); // solo si usas spring boot para cargar el controlador

        try {
            URL direccionFisica = this.recurso("/vistas/"+nombreVentana).getURL();
          
            fxmlLoader.setLocation(direccionFisica);
            root = fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException ex) {

            Logger.getLogger(VentanasServiceImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return root;
    }
```